# How to skip the string between patten in regex?

Tags: regex, preg-replace, preg-match

my string is

```
$str='insert into employees values('
```

I want to ignore everything between **insert into** and **(**. I want to skip **employees values** how should I skip it in regex?

input string:

```
insert into employees values( nextval( 'public.scheduled_charges_id_seq' ),'shrenik', 555, NULL)
```

required output:

```
insert into employees values( nextval( 'public.scheduled_charges_id_seq' ),'XXX', XXX, NULL);
```

I tried:

```
([0-9]|\'.*\')
```

I want to replace the confidential values in strings Which started as insert into the pattern should be limited to braces from inset into employees ( to where it ends .
can u please help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What's your goal here?

Comment: How does your pattern look so far?

Comment: Please give example of what exactly you are tying to match and an example of desired result after replace.

Comment: What do you mean by ` I want to skip employees values`?

Comment: Hello guys Added some more information related to what I want

Comment: How about: `\),\s?'([^']+)',\s?([0-9]+)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

Regex:

```
\),\s?'([^']+)',\s?([0-9]+)
```

Working regex example:

http://regex101.com/r/kR9gY4

PHP:

```
$str = "insert into employees values( nextval( 'public.scheduled_charges_id_seq' ),'XXX', 555, NULL);";

preg_match("/\),\s?'([^']+)',\s?([0-9]+)/", $str, $matches);

echo $matches[1] . ", " . $matches[2];
```

Output:

```
XXX, 555
```

---

Or if you're going to **replace** these values, you could do this:

Regex:

```
(?<=,)\s?[^,]+,\s?[^,]+(?=,)
```

Working regex example:

http://regex101.com/r/cJ4pM1

PHP:

```
$str = "insert into employees values( nextval( 'public.scheduled_charges_id_seq' ),'XXX', 555, NULL);";

echo preg_replace("/(?<=,)\s?[^,]+,\s?[^,]+(?=,)/", "'YYY', 999", $str);
```

Output:

```
insert into employees values( nextval( 'public.scheduled_charges_id_seq' ),'YYY', 999, NULL);
```

Comment: hi MElliott it should first find for the insert into in given string and the for any numerical value or value in '' up to closing brace of insert into )