# Replace in Regex

Tags: regex, preg-replace, preg-match

input string : "Any string or numeric character appears here

**insert into employees values( nextval( 'public.scheduled_charges_id_seq' ),'shrenik', 555, NULL,253,'Rahul')** This is my String"

required output: "Any string or numeric character appears here

**insert into employees values( nextval( 'public.scheduled_charges_id_seq' ),'XXX', XXX, NULL, XXX,'XXX')**

This is my String"

I tried :([0-9]|\'.*\')
**It must match "insert into" in given string** 
Want to replace the confidential values in strings Which started as insert into the pattern should be limited to braces from inset into employees ( to where it ends . can u please help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: Which parts of the string that you want to match are variable, and which are fixed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to skip the gstrin between patten in regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21680934/how-to-skip-the-gstrin-between-patten-in-regex)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `insert into employees values( nextval( 'public.scheduled_charges_id_seq' ),` is fixed and that you don't have any other function calls or sub-queries within your query, then you could do it like this:

```
// Set up test string
$statement = "Any string or numeric character appears here

insert into employees values( nextval( 'public.scheduled_charges_id_seq' ),'shrenik', 555, NULL,253,'Rahul') This is my String";

$pieces = preg_split('/\)[, ]/', $statement);
// print_r($pieces);
// $pieces[0] contains everything up to "... id_seq' " 
// $pieces[1] contains all of the fields you want to redact
// $pieces[2] contains everything after the closing )

$pieces[1] = preg_replace('/\'\w+\'|\d+/', 'XXX', $pieces[1]);
// print $pieces[1] . "\n";

$statement = $pieces[0] . ")," . $pieces[1] . ") " . $pieces[2];
print $statement . "\n";
```

Output:

```
Any string or numeric character appears here

insert into employees values( nextval( 'public.scheduled_charges_id_seq' ),XXX, XXX, NULL,XXX,XXX) This is my String
```

**EDITED:** *In respond to OP's comment about not using `preg_split`.*

You could use the less frequently used `preg_replace_callback`, which takes as its second argument a function callback which processes the array of matches to produce the replacement string that you want.  Documentation on `preg_replace_callback` can be [found here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php).

```
$statement = "Any string or numeric character appears here

insert into employees values( nextval( 'public.scheduled_charges_id_seq' ),'shrenik', 555, NULL,253,'Rahul') This is my String";

$statement = 
  preg_replace_callback('/(insert into(?:[^\)]+)\),)(.*)\) /', 
                        function($matches) {
                          return $matches[1] .
                                 preg_replace('/(^|,)[ ]*[^,]+/', '$1 XXX', $matches[2]) .
                                 ') ';
                        },
                        $statement);

print $statement . "\n";
```

The output is the same as in the previous example.

**The above two examples replace EVERY field in the `insert` query string.**

** EDITED:** *Added code sample below in response to OP's comment.*

If you would like to exclude certain terms from being replaced (for example, `NULL` and `NOW()`), then that complicates things.  You could do this like below, defining a constant which is a pipe-delimited string of terms that you do *not* want replaced with `XXX`.

```
$original_statement = 
  "insert into public.scheduled_charges VALUES ( nextval( 'public.scheduled_charges_id_seq' ), 4633, 9085042, 116164, 3, NULL, NULL, NULL, '055    ~..~00~..~140~..~7~..~RNT~..~Jan 1 2014 12:00AM', 875, NULL, 1, '01/01/2014', '12/31/2013', '01/01/2014', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NULL, '01/01/2014', NULL, '01/31/2014', NULL, NULL, 2414, NOW(), 2414, NOW() ) RETURNING id;";

define('IGNORE_TERMS', 'NULL|NOW()');

$replaced_statement = 
  preg_replace_callback('/(insert into(?:[^\)]+)\),)(.*)[ ]*\) /', 
                        function($matches) {
                          return $matches[1] .
                                 preg_replace_callback('/(^|,)([^,]+)/',
                                                       function($matches) {
                                                         $matches[2] = trim($matches[2]);
                                                         if (in_array(strtoupper($matches[2]),
                                                                      explode('|', IGNORE_TERMS))) {
                                                           return $matches[1] . ' ' . $matches[2];
                                                         }
                                                         else {
                                                           return $matches[1] . ' XXX';
                                                         }
                                                       },
                                                       $matches[2]) .
                                 ') ';
                        },
                        $original_statement);

print $original_statement . "\n";
print "\n";
print $replaced_statement . "\n";
```

This works and gives you the result that you're looking for.  **I'm not claiming that the code is pretty or even very flexible.**  But, *in this case*, it gets the job done for you.

Comment: This is what I expected. Can I do this without making it pieces? And it should match first string contain  'insert into' in given string

Comment: Can u please look into this statement:   $statement = "INSERT INTO
public.scheduled_charges
VALUES ( nextval( 'public.scheduled_charges_id_seq' ), 4633, 9085042, 116164, 3, NULL, NULL, NULL, '055~..~00~..~140~..~7~..~RNT~..~Jan 1 2014 12:00AM', 875, NULL, 1, '01/01/2014', '12/31/2013', '01/01/2014', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NULL, '01/01/2014', NULL, '01/31/2014', NULL, NULL, 2414, NOW(), 2414, NOW() ) RETURNING id;";

Comment: Need to replace the values in this SQL

Comment: What are you hoping the output would be?  Would all of the numbers, dates, texts (including things like `~140~`)... everything up to and including `NOW()` would become `NULL`?

Comment: I've modified the code sample.  Try your new statement with that regexp.

Comment: everything within ''(single quote),numbers except NULL and NOW which are in SQL bracket()

Comment: Hi Alvin,I want to keep null and NOW as it is

Comment: Hey Alvin I tried it but it gives same output as input can u please check it once on http://www.compileonline.com/execute_php_online.php ?

Comment: There was line break in the middle of the `$original_statement` assignment statement.  I have fixed it now.  Try to paste the code and see if works for you now.

Comment: Hi Alvin I want to add some more acceptance criteria if input like this "SELECT * FROM ar_payments_insert( 35422525, 1976, 40651, NULL, 9, 48516, NULL, NULL, 9, 3, 27, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 7932, NULL, 7, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '01/06/2014 10:16:27', '01/05/2014', 1500, 0, 0, 1500, 0.25, 0.35, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '3485', NULL, 0, 0, 0, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 32520 ) AS result;" Where first element in () is not as it was in previous.can u please update me on the same.can we update anything inside () as XXX instead of NULL and NOW()?

Comment: Glad that I could be of help and that you found the answer you needed.  Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Hello Alvin waiting for your positive response regarding statement added previously.Thank you.

Comment: @Shrenik - My hope is that I have already provided you with a thorough enough and clear enough answer to address the question that you originally posted, and that it was done so in a way that allows you to learn on your own how to adapt this solution to any changes that your problem may encounter. Please... enjoy the journey. Welcome to StackOverflow.